# Can I have Entitiy Framework (Core) Migrations create database scripts?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In production my program is not allowed to emit DDL statements. I need to provide the database admins with a script that's performing these steps.

Can I have Entity Framework (Core) Migrations create some kind of a delta T-SQL script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are a couple of ways:

1) Using [Package Manager Console Tools for EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#script-migration):

```
Script-Migration
```

2) Using the [command line tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet):

```
> dotnet ef migrations script -o scriptname.sql
```

Comment: Additionally you can apply the migration to a dev database, and use SSDT to generate a change script.

Answer (score 1):

I would expand on Steve Greene's answer in that if you want to script the delta changes you can do

```
dotnet ef migrations script <from migration> <to migration>
```

eg

```
dotnet ef migrations script AddNewTables AddAuditTable
```

to create a sql file you can do this

```
dotnet ef migrations script AddNewTables AddAuditTable -o update-script.sql
```

More detail here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli